# Checked Checkbox not updated in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a problem regarding checking checkbox by JS.When I checked the checkbox by JS it seems like in program that it's checked but in UI it's not updated .

if anyone have solution for this

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Check</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>    
    function getCheckedValue()
    {
    return ((document.getElementById("rock").checked));

     }

    function setCheckedValue(toBeChecked){
        document.getElementById(toBeChecked).checked="checked";
        alert((document.getElementById(toBeChecked).checked))
        alert($('#'+toBeChecked).attr('checked'))
    }
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>What kind/s of music do you listen to?</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="music" name="music" id="rock" value="rock" >
        <label for="rock">Rock</label>
        <input type="button" value="Get" onclick="alert(getCheckedValue())">
        <input type="button" value="Set" onclick="setCheckedValue('rock') ">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked after getting response from all of your efforts and the working code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Check</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>    
    function getCheckedValue()
    {
    return (document.getElementById("rock").checked);
    //return $('input[name=music]').checked;
     }

    function setCheckedValue(checkboxName,toBeChecked){
        $('input[name='+checkboxName+']').prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>What kind/s of music do you listen to?</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <input type="checkbox" class="music" name="music" id="rock" value="rock" >
        <label for="rock">Rock</label>
        <input type="button" value="Get" onclick="alert(getCheckedValue())">
        <input type="button" value="Set" onclick="setCheckedValue('music','rock') ">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using attr I would highly recommend you use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

> The preferred cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to check for a "truthy" value on the element's property using one of the following:

```
if ( elem.checked )
if ( $(elem).prop("checked") )
if ( $(elem).is(":checked") )
```

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value.

```
$("input").prop("disabled", false);
$("input").prop("checked", true);
$("input").val("someValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function setCheckedValue(toBeChecked){
    document.getElementById(toBeChecked).checked=true;
    alert((document.getElementById(toBeChecked).checked))
    alert($('#'+toBeChecked).prop('checked'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery-mobile appends classes for such things. Basically within that one input/label pair you have the following:

```
<div class="ui-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="music" name="music" id="rock" value="rock">
  <label for="rock" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-  wrapperels="span" data-icon="checkbox-off" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off ui-checkbox-on ui-btn-up-c">

    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">Rock</span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

What you need to do is find a way to remove and add the classes to the label and span tags. I've done this for the label, but not for the span as I'm about to finally get some sleep.

```
function setCheckedValue(toBeChecked){
    document.getElementById(toBeChecked).checked="checked";
    $("label[for='rock']").addClass("ui-checkbox-off");
    $("label[for='rock']").addClass("ui-checkbox-on");
}
```

I did stumble across:

```
$("#checkbox-label").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

From: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-is-the-most-effective-way-of-unchecking-a-checkbox

Not entirely the same question, I know but slightly relevant. I didn't have the chance to finagle with it and get it to work...nor did I look much more into it to see if it does even work.

In short, the property is being set to "checked", however, the elements need to have their css refreshed in order to accommodate the new 'state'.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Every One For there Support,Now after seeing all the answer I have reached my solution 
Below is the code 

    function setCheckedValue(toBeChecked){
      //document.getElementById(toBeChecked).checked="checked";
      $("input[name=music]").prop("checked", true);
      $("label[for='rock']").addClass("ui-checkbox-on");
      $("span").addClass(" ui-icon-checkbox-on");
     }

Comment: I there any way to give the style in Span ...As I have given span style for checkbox,it takes for all span element

Comment: Sumit, I'll look into this more a bit later when I get home from work and let you know if I find anything. I did mess around briefly last night trying to get it to work, but was unsuccessful.