# Checked Radio Button not updated in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I have checked radio button using Jquery buts its not updated in UI .
Anyone has any idea .below is my snippets...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Radio Button</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getValue() {  
    alert("Value is :"+$('input[name=animal]:checked').val());
    }

    function setValue(toBeSetID) {  
    $("input[name=animal][id=radio-choice-2]").prop("checked", true);
    $("label[for='rock']").addClass("ui-radio-on");
    alert("Value is :"+$('input[name=animal]:checked').val());
    }
    </script>
    </head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Radio Button</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">   
    <input type="radio" name="animal" id="cat" value="Cat" />
    <label for="cat">Cat</label>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"/>
    <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
    <input type="button" value="Get Radio Button Value" onclick="getValue();">
    <input type="button" value="Set Radio Button Value" onclick="setValue();">
</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Its Checked by programm as alert box says But not updated in UI.

Comment: I think its same as your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10425246/705773

Comment: Ya a little bit but its not updated in UI and the problen is with span .How can i give a style to a specific span element which is bind to a specific radio button.If I will add class ui-radio-on to span it will update all span element .Any Idea regarding this??

Answer (score 1):

As Chase says in his answer to your other question, you have to refresh the jQuery Mobile widget when you change the `checked` property of the underlying form element. This can be done by writing:

```
$("input[name=animal][id=radio-choice-2]")
    .prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

That way, you do not have to manipulate the classes yourself, the mobile widget does all the work.

Note in passing that your selector targets an element that has an `id` attribute, so it can be simplified:

```
$("#radio-choice-2").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: Will this work for normal jquery. I mean not in jquerymobile. I ran into the same issue where the radio button will be checked but it's html attribute of checked is not updated.